# Nintendo account with Super Mario Run

Tags: super-mario-run, nintendo-account

I'm thinking of spending $10 to buy the Super Mario Run upgrade. If I link a Nintendo account to Super Mario Run, (I already did.) and if I buy the upgrade, will it sync to my Nintendo account and transfer over multiple devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will. I purchased the upgrade on my iPad. When I ran Super Mario Run on my iPhone, after logging in to my Nintendo account, it not only synced the purchase but my progress (levels completed, coins, etc.) as well.

I don't know if it matters or not, but I use the same iTunes account and Nintendo account on both devices.

Comment: As the Nintendo account is completely separate from iTunes, then only having the same Nintendo account will matter.

Comment: Ok, now I want to know, when they come out with Android and such, will the purchase sync with that too, because it is a Nintendo account? I have a Kindle and I wanna know if it will sync. (I know it isn't out yet.)

Comment: I would hope (and guess) that yes it will sync between iOS and Android, but it's also possible they won't allow that. I don't think we'll be able to answer that until Super Mario Run is released for Android (or Nintendo makes an announcement regarding this).

Comment: @Yoshi24517 btw it doesn’t sync across platforms https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/303939/1478

Comment: @JacobKrall I'm talking about when you log in to your Nintendo Account. The other post doesn't mention that.